# ngrx/effects use delay operator with value from state

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

in my application, I tracking for session time

```
  @Effect()
  session$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(authAction.RESET_SESSION)
    .switchMap(_ => Observable.of({ type: authAction.LOGOUT })
                .delay(600000);
```

*every time that `RESET_SESSION` action is called, the logout action waits 10 minutes.

in my application, I get session time from the server and store it on state after login. how I can use this store value in delay? ( because in ngrx store return observable and not object of state)

something like this:

```
 @Effect()
  session$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(authAction.RESET_SESSION)
    .switchMap(_ => Observable.of({ type: authAction.LOGOUT })
                .delay(this.store.pluck('auth','sessionTime'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to inject the store into the Effects through the constructor. Something like:

```
@Injectable()
export FooEffects {
   @Effect()
    session$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(authAction.RESET_SESSION)
    .mergeMap(_ => this.store.select(getSessionTime)) //getSessionTime would be a selector
    .switchMap(delay => Observable.of({ type: authAction.LOGOUT }).delay(delay));

   ctor(
   private actions$: Actions,
   private store: Store<rootState>){}
}
```